# Is app.config name hard-coded or can it be modified?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, app-config

I know that when building in VS, `app.config` gets copied to `<configuration>/<app-name>.exe.config`. I believe this copy step is performed by msbuild, which VS uses for building?

I've seen some suggestions that this can be customised through build settings or properties or something, but I can't find a definitive answer.

My two linked questions are:

1. Who/what copies the `app.config` file to the output directory during building? And at what point in the build?
2. Can I control the name of the file that is searched for e.g. change it to `Jeff.config` or `{ConfigurationName}.cfg`?

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, but you may need to be mindful as you're getting deeper in the pipeline. If you'll check this file:

> Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

You can find couple of interesting targets:

PrepareForBuild: Prepare the prerequisites for building.

```
  <Target Name="PrepareForBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(PrepareForBuildDependsOn)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(AppConfig)" Condition="'$(AppConfig)'!=''">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>

    <FindAppConfigFile PrimaryList="@(None)" SecondaryList="@(Content)" TargetPath="$(TargetFileName).config" Condition="'$(AppConfig)'==''">
      <Output TaskParameter="AppConfigFile" ItemName="AppConfigWithTargetPath"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="AppConfigFile" PropertyName="AppConfig"/>
    </FindAppConfigFile>

    <!-- Create the directories for intermediate and final build products, and any other arbitrary directories. -->
    <!-- We are going to continue on error here so that if the tree is read only we will still get intellisense -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir);$(IntermediateOutputPath);@(DocFileItem->'%(RelativeDir)');@(CreateDirectory)" ContinueOnError="True"/>

  </Target>
```

which builds up `AppConfigWithTargetPath` ItemGroup (and this itemgroup is used in many other targets).
And another target, which performs the actual copying - `_CopyAppConfigFile` :Copy the application config file.

```
  <Target
      Name="_CopyAppConfigFile"
      Condition=" '@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)' != '' "
      Inputs="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"
      Outputs="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath->'$(OutDir)%(TargetPath)')">

    <!--
        Copy the application's .config file, if any.
        Not using SkipUnchangedFiles="true" because the application may want to change the app.config and not have an incremental build replace it.
        -->
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"
        DestinationFiles="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath->'$(OutDir)%(TargetPath)')"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
        Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
        RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"             
      UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </Copy>
  </Target>
```

Knowing how it's being copied - you can affect what should be copied.
Most clean way is to define\overwrite a value in $(AppConfig) property - then everything will have to use this new specified config.

Depends on how you build things - you may need to create pre-solution file to hook in or modify explicitly your build script to pass extra parameters. Or you may search in your csproj files and edit file name directly there.

Comment: Interesting, thankyou. I had thought I could simply add a project pre-build event `copy $(ProjectDir)App.$(ConfigurationName).config $(ProjectDir)App.config` but apparently this doesn't work... I'm assuming it happens _after_ the stuff you're referencing?

Comment: You can do it too, but you've asked a bit different questions ;). 
The simplest trick I did for such config copying was to wire up one command that overwrites app.config with particular 'Jeff.config'. But I just explained some bits about how is the pipeline works